# Using the xlsx package in R

Tags: r, package, xlsx

I am trying to export a data table from R into excel. I installed the xlsx package and it gave me the following output:

```
Installing package into ‘C:/Users/Jack/Documents/R/win-library/3.4’
(as ‘lib’ is unspecified)
--- Please select a CRAN mirror for use in this session ---
trying URL 
'https://mirrors.sorengard.com/cran/bin/windows/contrib/3.4/xlsx_0.5.7.zip'
Content type 'application/zip' length 401236 bytes (391 KB)
downloaded 391 KB

package ‘xlsx’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked

The downloaded binary packages are in
    C:\Users\Jack\AppData\Local\Temp\Rtmp04FZrB\downloaded_packages
```

Then when I went to load with `library("xlsx")`, It said:

```
Loading required package: rJava
Loading required package: xlsxjars
```

Then I tried to do the line:

```
write.xlsx(x,file="myfile.xlsx",sheetName="Sheet1",append=False)
```

but it never let me enter the command, it kept pushing me onto a new line.

Can somebody give me some guidance on what is wrong?

Comment: what do you mean with something wrong? I don't see any error or warning

Comment: Fair point, Updated question.

Comment: "kept pushing me onto a new line" suggests a missing quote or parenthesis.

Comment: Also, you don't need quotes when you call packages: `library(xlsx)` should do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just tried running this on my R console.
It's because in R, logical `FALSE` should be capitalized or just called as `F`.
With `write.xlsx(x, file = "myfile.xlsx", sheetName = "Sheet1", append = False)`, it thinks `False` is a predefined variable.
Try `write.xlsx(x, file = "myfile.xlsx", sheetName = "Sheet1", append = FALSE)`. It works for me.